# C# enums from database all the way up to AngularJS constants

Tags: c#, angularjs, sql-server, enums, asp.net-core

I need some guidance on using enums generically throughout our web project. In more details, i mean that our lookup tables, like PersonType, PrivilegeType, ContactType etc. will be created in a dll (or C# files, one file per enum), say Enums.dll, and then thses enums would be added as constants to our 'common' AngularJS module, resulting in something like this for example:

```
angular
.module('common', [])
.constant('ePrivilegeType', {
    NoPermissions: 1,
    ViewOnly: 2,
    ViewAndUpdate: 3
})
.constant('ePersonType', {
    Administration: 1,
    Student: 2,
    Father: 3,
    Mother: 4
});
```

Is this kind of workflow common and acceptable? How can we achive this kind of workflow? It will make our lives much easier with working with enums thoughout all our project.

Answer (score 3):

If these matchings are only needed for showing to the user (e.g. in a combo box), I used a web api that provided these values for me. So within the data objects that are used within angularjs are still this magic numbers. But from the server under `/api/enum/privilegeTypes` you'll get back an array of objects in the format

```
[{
  value: 1,
  name: "NoPermissions",
  description: "This is not allowed"
}, ...]
```

On the server (in .net) you create a simple class (e.g. `EnumWrapper`) and a factory method (e.g. `EnumWrapper.From<PrivilegeType>()` or `EnumWrapper.From(enumTypeName)`) which iterates through all enum values (with `Enum.GetValues()`) and creates the desired list and returns it.

```
public enum PrivilegeType
{
    [Description("Access not allowed")]
    NoPermissions = 1,
    [Description("Read only ")]
    ViewOnly = 2,
    [Description("Read and write access")]
    ViewAndUpdate = 3
}
```

By using this approach you still have the magic numbers in your data objects but you can present the available options to the user with some meaningful text and if you change the enum values or names you only have to change them on the server side and not on the client side.